# Does $\frac {z^5}{\sin z^2-z^2}$ have a non-isolated singularity at $0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, residue-calculus, singularity-theory

Does  $\frac {z^5}{\sin z^2-z^2}$ have a non-isolated singularity at $0$? If so, is it not meaningful to discuss its residue at $0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have holomorphic/ holomorphic it shouldn't be non-isolated (you need a accumulation point of zeroes in the denominator for a non isolated singularity)  and taking 
$$\sin(z^2)=z^2 -\frac{z^6}{3!}\pm \dots$$ 
gives you 
$$\frac{z^5}{z^2-z^2 - \frac{z^6}{3!}\pm \dots}= \frac{1}{-\frac{z}{3!}\pm\dots}$$
which has a pole of order $1$ at zero.

If the singularity is not isolated there is no sense in calculating the residue (which I guess won't be possible at all) because all the nice theorems won't work. In the definition of my complex analysis course we need the poles to be discrete (having no accumulation point) else we won't say it is a residue anyway.

Comment: Thank you. BTW you missed out the negative sign in the last denominator. Yes I initially thought the function has a simple pole too, but Wolfram is claiming it has no pole: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pole+of+z5%2F%28sin%28z2%29+-+z2%29+ What do you reckon?

Comment: @Ryan Well but [here wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Residue%5Bz%5E5%2F%28Sin%5Bz%5E2%5D+-+z%5E2%29%2C+%7Bz%2C+0%7D%5D) supports me, you can't have a residue without having a pole